# call multiple items from a list, seperately?

Tags: python-3.x, list, set, user-input

so, after finally figuring out how to call multiple objects at once from a list, i've encountered another issue; i can't seem to call multiple items unless they're in order. i want to read user input and interpret it as commands regardless of the order of words entered.

```
command = input("Enter command: ")
keywords = command.split()

if set(keywords).issubset(['hello','world']):print("Hello world!")
```

this prints "Hello world!" when the input is "hello world" or "world hello", but i want it to work when input in any order; for example "to the world, hello" or "hello to the world".

Comment: terminology note: "call" is not the correct term here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a issues at play here to allow any perumutation of 'world' and 'hello':

1. By default, string comparisons in Python are case-sensitive. Prevent this by using the `.lower` method.
2. when matching strings non-alphanumerics like ',' or '.' can be left over in `.split`. So you'll have to clean the input to be able to put in 'to the world, hello' since the split would output `world,`.
3. Just ask for the set with `{}` in the if statement.

```
    # Convert to lowercase to allow for case-insensitive matching
    command = input("Enter command: ").lower()
    
    # Remove non-alphanumeric characters except spaces to allow for strings such as "to the world, hello" 
    cleaned_command = ''.join(c if c.isalnum() or c.isspace() else ' ' for c in command)
    
    # Split the cleaned command into words
    keywords = cleaned_command.split()
    
    # Check if the set of valid keywords is a subset of the input keywords
    if {'hello', 'world'}.issubset(keywords):
        print("Hello world!")
```

Answer (score 0):

- use `issuperset` instead of `issubset`, but it will not solve your complete problem
- Note: `split()` method splits the string by ' '(space), you have to take care of all special characters that may be used along with words eg `world!` or `hello,` will not split. you have to add condition for all these.
- If you can describe your problem more we can use `regex` on it.